# How to trigger hive sql through oozie having JAVA UDF

Tags: hive, oozie

I have a hive sql which I am trying to trigger through oozie workflow.This hql uses UDF. So, I have below steps in my hql.

ADD JAR XXXXX; 
create temporary function ZZZZ as '...';

Then I have my actual hql which used UDF.

When I am trying to run this hql. I am getting below error.

Error: Error while processing statement: XXXXX.jar does not exist (state=,code=1)

My JAR file is inside HDFS.

```
<action name="hive2-b2e4">
        <hive2 xmlns="uri:oozie:hive2-action:0.1">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <configuration>
                <property>
                    <name>oozie.libpath</name>
                    <value>/user/manishs/lib</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>oozie.use.system.libpath</name>
                    <value>true</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>oozie.wf.rerun.failnodes</name>
                    <value>true</value>
                </property>
            </configuration>
            <jdbc-url>jdbc:hive2://ggvahdpm10:10000/default</jdbc-url>
            <script>/user/manishs/file.hql</script>
              <param>day=${wf:actionData(&#39;shell-edf3&#39;)[&#39;fromDay&#39;]}</param>
            <file>/user/manishs/file.hql#imps.hql</file>
            <file>/user/manishs/lib/XXXXX.jar#XXXXXX.jar</file>
        </hive2>
        <ok to="End"/>
        <error to="Kill"/>
    </action>
```

Can you please help?

Regards, 
Manish

Comment: I write it as an answer but this just a few hints: 
you already specified the oozie.libpath: /user/manishs/lib, maybe you can directly access the libpath!? 

Check this example:
<file>/users/blabla/testfile.sh#testfile</file>
<archive>/users/blabla/testarchive.jar#testarchive</archive>

Jar defined as archive, and like this: 
/user/manishs/lib/XXXXX.jar#XXXXXX 

https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.2.0-incubating/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a3.2.2.1_Adding_Files_and_Archives_for_the_Job